# Exception using EL-Injection

Tags: locale, prettyfaces

I'm currently trying to setup my project using pretty faces. The basic navigation and parameter setting works, but when I'm trying to inject the "locale" into a sessionScoped bin, prettyfaces throws an exception, saying

> PrettyFaces: Exception occurred while processing  for URL

That's my config:

```
    <url-mapping id="locale">
  <pattern value="/#{language: CurrentUser.language}" />
  <view-id value="/faces/index.xhtml" />
</url-mapping>

<url-mapping parentId="locale" id="portal"> 
    <pattern value="/portal" /> 
    <view-id value="/faces/index.xhtml" />
</url-mapping>
```

If I remove the EL-injection, the rule works, but ofc. CurrentUser.language is not set, then.

Edit: i've now tried it with query-params - but also theres a "null" somewhere:

```
http://localhost:8090/portal/?language=en
```

causing:

```
PrettyFaces: Exception occurred while processing mapping<portal:#{currentUser.language}> for query parameter named<language> null
```

with config

```
<url-mapping id="portal"> 
    <pattern value="/portal/" /> 
    <view-id value="/faces/index.xhtml" />
    <query-param name="language">#{currentUser.language}</query-param>
</url-mapping>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to inject into a Locale object field? There is probably no default converter for String -> Locale in EL/JSF, so you should probably inject into a Field, then use an `<action>#{currentUser.language}</action>` to convert that into a Locale object and set it.